# solve equation in positive integers

Tags: diophantine-equations, natural-numbers, quadratics

Can anybody help me with this equation?

Solve in $\mathbb{N}$:
$$3x^2 - 7y^2 +1=0$$
One solution is the pair $(3,2)$, and i think this is the only pair of positive integers that can be a solution. Any idea?

Comment: Consider that $ \ 7y^2 - 3x^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ is the equation of a "vertical hyperbola" with asymptotes of $ \ y \ = \ \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{7}} x \ . $  So the curve in the first quadrant approaches a line with a positive irrational slope.  Will there be any other ordered pairs with integer values on or near that line?

Comment: So? can you please further explain ?

Comment: You indicate that you are only looking for solutions that are integers.  Any solutions of the equation have to lie on the hyperbola, which asymptotically approaches the straight line $ \ y \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{3}{7}} x \ $ in the first quadrant.  So are there any other _integer_ values for $ \ y \ $ close to $ \  \sqrt{\frac{3}{7}} x \ , $ with $ \ x \ $ being an integer?

Comment: no there aren't, but what about (3;2) ? is there any other way of solving this (by modulo reduction maybe) because this is a pure number theory problem

Comment: Yes, (3,2) is on the hyperbola, so it is a solution.  It is what the relationship between $ \ y \ $ and $ \ x \ $ tends to beyond that point that suggests there won't be any more integer solutions.  I suppose you could look at $ \ y \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{3x^2 + 1}{7}} \ $ and consider whether $ \ 7n^2 \ $ can have the form $ \ 3m^2 + 1 \ $ .

Comment: It occurred to me that checking the _decimal_ value of $ \ \sqrt{\frac{3}{7}} \ $ might produce something useful.  This turns out to be 0.65465367... , which suggests the rational number $ \ \frac{654}{999} \ = \ \frac{218}{333} \ \approx \ 0.654654654... \ $ .  So we manage to eke out one more ordered pair, (333, 218) , but this approach doesn't seem to generalize well (using longer repeating decimal "blocks" doesn't readily turn up anything else).  The answer provided by **Greg Martin** is the direct method (unfortunately, I'm only learning about (not-)Pell's equations currently...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions in positive integers. $7y^2-3x^2=1$ is an example of a "Pell equation", and there are standard methods for finding solutions to Pell equations.

For example, the fact that $(x,y)=(2,3)$ is a solution to $7y^2-3x^2=1$ is equivalent to noting that $(2\sqrt7+3\sqrt3)(2\sqrt7-3\sqrt3)=1$. The fundamental unit in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{21})$ is $55+12\sqrt{21}$; in particular, $(55+12\sqrt{21})(55-12\sqrt{21})=1$. Consequently, if we calculate $(2\sqrt7+3\sqrt3)(55+12\sqrt{21}) = 218 \sqrt{7}+333 \sqrt{3}$, it follows that $(218 \sqrt{7}+333 \sqrt{3})(218 \sqrt{7}-333 \sqrt{3})=1$, or $7\cdot218^2 - 3\cdot333^2=1$.

You can get infinitely many solutions $(x_n,y_n)$ to $7y^2 - 3x^2=1$ by expanding $(2\sqrt7+3\sqrt3)(55+12\sqrt{21})^n = y_n \sqrt{7}+x_n \sqrt{3}$. Your solution corresponds to $n=0$, while the previous paragraph is $n=1$; for example, $n=2$ yields $x_2=36627$ and $y_2=23978$.

Answer (score 1):

For some Pell equations. For special cases, there is a formula describing their solutions.

If the equation: $aX^2-qY^2=f$ rational root $\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$

Solutions can be written using the following equation Pell:  $p^2-aqs^2=1$

Solutions have the form:

$Y=(2aps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$

$X=(2qps\pm(p^2+aqs^2))\sqrt{\frac{f}{a-q}}$

According to these decisions can be found double this solution:

$Y_2=Y+2as(Yqs-Xp)$

$X_2=X+2p(Yqs-Xp)$

If the other root is rational: $\sqrt{\frac{f}{a}}$
Solution has the form:

$Y=2ps\sqrt{fa}$

$X=(p^2+aqs^2)\sqrt{\frac{f}{a}}$

Must take into account that the number: $p,s$ can be any character.