# Integral points on a curve parametrized by quadratics.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics, nonlinear-system

I would like to know the integer solutions to the non-linear equations

$$x=\frac{\sqrt7}{7}\left(\frac{t^2+\frac{3}{7}}{t^2-\frac{3}{7}}\right)$$ and

$$y=\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{7}\left(\frac{t}{t^2 - \frac{3}{7}} \right)$$.

where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t^2 \neq \frac{3}{7}$.

I was wondering if there are general techniques for finding integer values of such equations. Finding separate integer values for $x$ and $y$ is not that hard. But making sure both $x$ and $y$ are integers is rather difficult. With the aid of computer, I have been able to find values for $x$ and $y$ by solving the equation for integers values of $y$ ranging between $1$ to $1000$, and checking if the corresponding $x$ values would be an integer. Those values are $(2,3)$ and $(218, 333)$ given by $t=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{21}+\frac{2}{3}$ and $t=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2331}+\frac{218}{333}$.

I have not been able to come up with a general pattern. Do we even know if there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Hint: eliminate $t$ between the equations and you get a diophantine equation in $x,y$. Btw, your values don't seem to check out, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%287%29+%2F+7+%28t%5E2+%2B+1%2F7%29+%2F+%28t%5E2+-+1%2F7%29+where+t+%3D+sqrt%287%29+%2F+21+%2B+2+%2F+3) for example.

Comment: You are right! My apologies, I should have used $\frac{3}{7}$ instead of $\frac{1}{7}$. I will update the equation.

Comment: Also, I have derived these equations because I was solving a Diophantine equation: 

see
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220737/solve-the-following-equation-7a2-3b2-1-where-a-b-are-two-positive-intege

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/661795/291201) for how to solve it.

Comment: I see! So I believe it answers the part of my question about the the number of solutions, which is infinitely many. But I am still interested to know the specific answer to my question. Is there a way to find integer values of $x$ and $y$ without having to solve the diophantine equation and get them directly from the parametrization in terms of $t$?

Comment: I don't see how this type of parametrization could simplify the problem. Quite the contrary I'd say, which is precisely why my first hint was to eliminate that extra variable.

Comment: Most probably you are right that approaching the problem in this manner might not simplify the problem; however, knowing different ways of solving a problem could be very insightful sometimes. It might not come in handy in this case, but who knows maybe on a different problem, the methods used to solve it in this way could be extremely helpful.

Comment: It never hurts to try, of course. That said, it would be rare to simplify a diophantine equation like this one by parametrizing it in terms of a new *real*-valued variable.

Comment: More two solutions were found.
$(x,y)=(23978, 36627)$ with $t=\frac{1}{256389}\sqrt{7}+\frac{23978}{36627}$,

$(x,y)=(2637362, 4028637)$ with $t=\frac{1}{28200459}\sqrt{7}+\frac{2637362}{4028637}$

Comment: $t^2+\frac 37 = (t^2-\frac 37 )(1+\frac{\frac 67}{t^2-\frac 37})$

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice is that $t$ cannot just be any real number; the condition that $x$ and $y$ are integers forces $t$ to be an algebraic number of rather low degree, by the looks of it at most degree $4$, possibly just degree $2$. Let's try to find an integer polynomial that $t$ must be a root of by manipulating the expressions for $x$ and $y$ a bit:

Dividing $x$ by $y$ cancels a lot of the mess, and we see that
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{t^2+\tfrac37}{2t},$$
where $x$ and $y$ are integers. Clearing denominators then shows that$$7yt^2-14xt+3y=0,$$
and so $t$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial with integral coefficients, so $t$ lies in a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. The discriminant of this polynomial is
$$\Delta=196x^2-84y^2=28(7x^2-3y^2),$$
and plugging the expressions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ back in shows that
$$7x^2-3y^2=1.\tag{1}$$
In particular $t\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, and $(x,y)$ is a solution to a Pell equation. Or more traditionally, the pair $(7x,y)$ is a solution to the Pell equation
$$X^2-21Y^2=7.$$
Of course Pell equations have been studied for millennia, their solutions are well understood and effectively computable, and thousands of near-identical questions on them exist on this site. Expressing $t$ in terms of either $x$ or $y$ is then a matter of routine algebra.

Answer (score 0):

> With the aid of computer, I have been able to find values for x and y by solving the equation for integers values of y ranging between 1 to 1000, and checking if the corresponding x values would be an integer.

If you use Python, there is a Sympy module specially dedicated to Diophantine equations: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html